# How to find a webelement by a part of an href / url using selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, url

I am trying to find a web element by (a part of) a URL using Selenium VBA.
I know we can find web elements using

```
driver.findelementbyxpath('//a[@href="'+url+'"]')
```

However, this only works if you know the entire URL. This does not work for me because I only know the first part of the URL.

Example: the web element's URL is something like: `www.website.com/nameofwebpage-h23&i^%`

and I only know `www.website.com/nameofwebpage`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains` function of XPath to construct the XPath expression.

Try something like below:

```
//a[contains(@href,'www.website.com/nameofwebpage')]
```

Or you can use `starts-with` function, something like below:

```
//a[starts-with(@href,'www.website.com/nameofwebpage')]
```

Comment: [xpath cheat sheet](https://devhints.io/xpath) the method is different for VBA but the XPath is not